# Inkscape custom pattern - scaling and adjusting issue (or bug)?

Tags: inkscape, vector, patterns

So I created this **custom pattern** #2548 like shown below, and applied the pattern to a plain circle.

[image: Custom pattern creation and application]

Instantly when applying the pattern to the circle, it is applied like five times bigger than it was created. Why is that, and how can I apply a custom pattern in its **original size** as it has been created to shapes?

Also, when I create a pattern this way and then try to adjust its size or angle with the Node Tool, why is it that the **adjusting nodes** appear like half a meter off the page?

[image: Nodes for adjusting pattern are way off the page]

Is this a bug?

Explanations or help much appreciated.

--

Inkscape version is 1.1-dev (78e9eb4, 2020-12-04)

Here's the Inkscape file
https://ufile.io/vacf0gnu

Comment: you could create an issue [here](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues)

Comment: I guess some Inkscape users avoid using  pattern fills due the lack of control.You have met a part of it. The fill cannot be expanded to tiled independent shapes and one cannot trust the pattern scaling and placement stays when exported as general (non-Inkscape) SVG. A workaroud is to tile clones and insert a clipping path which is the actual shape to be filled.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I've noticed this before especially in Inkscape 1.0. It's quite annoying.  I'd say it's probably a bug because I don't remember the problem existing in 0.92.

But anyway, as for a fix, you can click and drag the X to bring the pattern controls closer to your object, and you can adjust scaling and rotation of the pattern using the controls.

For example

[image]

And just to check this still renders OK in browsers here's [the optimized SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/S71.svg) for that one object I adjusted.  Looks OK in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Another possible workaround I found is to open the document properties, set units to px, and scaling to 1.  This seems to fix the pattern scaling issue. Ultimately, I think this must be the real source of the bug. Changing a documents units shouldn't change the behaviour of Inkscape's patterns.

Example

[image]

Comment: I downloaded and opened your linked SVG in Illustrator. The result was totally different - a solid white circle. Can be caused by the fact I use Legacy stuff. But quite new Affinity Designer showed a transparent circle. Does modern Illustrator show it as intended?

Comment: @user287001 Illustrator has shockingly bad support for SVG standards. It doesn't seem to be a priority for Adobe. I use Illustrator CC (2018, not the most recent) and it's just as bad.  I'm really not surprised it doesn't work. I've never used Affinity Designer.  Check the SVG in a browser. It's absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's very helpful. I already have opened a bug here:
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/4146.
On a side note, do you guys have an idea how not to have thin white lines in the pattern as can be seen from Bill's exported SVG here:
https://svgshare.com/i/S71.svg
https://i.imgur.com/IdBg3eV.png

Comment: @David.P these are conflation artifacts. If you want to avoid them, maybe don't use a pattern for this.  Instead, just create a pattern of stripes manually, group it with a rectangle filled pink as the background, and set the circle as a clipping mask on the group.